# Does Hibernate support PL/SQL record types?

Tags: java, hibernate, plsql

I am using Hibernate as ORM tool in my application, and I am calling stored procedure for it, but I did not see any PL/SQL record type handling in Hibernate,

Is there any setting needed in Hibernate to support PL/SQL record type?

Note -

Hibernate internally uses JDBC, and JDBC does not support Record type, How hibernate resolve this by supporting Record type

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to create hibernate entity for each stored procedure return type and register them into hibernate config.

> hibernateSession.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM FOO").addEntity(Foo.class);

And add Foo config like:

```
<!-- Foo.hbm.xml -->
...
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.sample.Foo" table="FOO" ...>
        ...
    </class>
    ...

</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer @Ritesh K yes this can be a solution, but we not aware of all record type in stored procedure, user can call any stored procedure, so its very difficult to  find each record type in complete data base and write entity for each of them. Is there any generic data container hibernate provided for handling it

Comment: @Afgan We have to identify all SP record type and create entities for them. Otherwise how Hibernate would know about mapping from resultset.

Comment: Our Oracle data base have near about 2.5 lac SP, it will easy to find procedure and there record type, but same time it will be very complex to crate entities for each record type. Is there any automation in this  ?

Comment: Note -Hibernate internally uses JDBC, and JDBC does not support Record type, How hibernate resolve this by supporting Record type

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the record into columns for eg:

`SELECT (q.r).* FROM (SELECT r) q;`

where `r` is your record(s)

Then you can treat it like any other query and map to an entity via `SQLQuery.addEntity` for eg.